# Delete character "\n" from string with read

Tags: printf, buffer, stat, opendir

I've to do a project but I hit a issue. 
I receive a string from a read but when I would see what data are in my buffer, it shows an "\n" at the end of the file. However I don't need it to use after to deal with a argument in my function.

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main() 
{

char buf[100];
read(1, buf, sizeof(buf));
printf("%s", &buf);
// If I write: "/tmp/", printf shows: "/tmp/\n"
DIR* drp = opendir(buf);
// Logically: no such file or directory
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem in how you read string from `stdin`. `read` function waits until you enter a newline or other EOF key. But it includes this last symbol in the result.

1) I think you better use `scanf`.

```
scanf("%s", buf);
```

2) Or you need to take care of the last symbol by yourself.

```
char buf[100];
char res[100];
int n = read(1, buf, sizeof(buf));
if(n > 0) {
   memcpy(res, buf, n - 1);
} else {
   printf("Error while reading\n");
}
```